# find "/p" with preg_match in first place of string

Tags: php, preg-match

Small problem:

```
$content='/p test some text';
```

when "/p" is in front of the line the string should be exploded to an array

```
if(preg_match('^(/p)',$content)==true) {
$private=explode(" ",$content,3);
}
```

i think their is an error, but i've no idea for the correct search parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(No need to compare it with true, because if it doesn't find anything it returns an empty array, which then is false. Also you need [delimiters](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php) for your regex and escape the slash with a backslash)

```
$content='/p test some text';
if(preg_match('/^\/p/',$content)) {
             //^    ^ See delimiters
    $private=explode(" ",$content,3);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not a simple test

```
if ($content{0} == '/' && $content{1} == 'p' ) { 
    $private=explode(" ",$content,3); 
}
```